# Is it possible to use US Direct Consular Filing when not living one's own country?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, marriage

I'm an Argentine, and my fianceé has dual US/Mexico nationality. There is no USCIS office here in Argentina (only an Embassy), so getting the visa through the DCF process (Direct Consular Filing - incredibly faster than the traditional route) is not possible. But Mexico City has one. Is it at all possible, if we both move to Mexico, to get the visa that way?